# PyCharm UML editor not present?

Tags: plugins, uml, pycharm

I'm using the community edition 3.4.1, and per [Jet Brains](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Working+with+UML+class+diagrams+in+PyCharm?_ga=1.201253294.1242010323.1401891860) , I'm don't see the menu options to show UML.

I did try to enable the UML plugins, but the linked page to do that from the above link is dead. That's probably the issue, can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Jet Brains support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/home should be able to enlighten you much better. Both the knowledge base, community forums and last but not least you can open a support request ticket that will allocate you a piece of JetBrains professional to help you. In my opinion Stack Overflow is not quite the right place (check http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for your otherwise useful and interesting question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is not dead. Just remove the / at the end.

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html

Answer (score 21):

For what it's worth, the free Community Edition of PyCharm does not support UML integration.

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html